# CUDA atomic and non atomic memory access

Tags: cuda, malloc, free, semaphore, atomic

I have two CUDA functions that manipulate linked lists in global memory. The function `pmalloc` removes the head element of one of the lists. It first chooses a list and then calls `pmallocBucket` which actually removes the head element. Should the chosen list be empty, `pmalloc` will try other lists. The `pfree` function on the other hand will insert a new head element into a list.

Mutual exclusion is achieved through semaphores, one each for each linked list. The implementation for the semaphores is from the book *CUDA By Example*. In some other test code, the semaphore works perfectly.

The problem I have with the code is the following: Sometimes, several threads will try to access the same linked list simultaneously. These accesses are succesfully sequentialized by the semaphore, but sometimes, a thread will remove the same head element from the list as a previous thread. This may happen immediately consecutively, or there can be one or more other threads in between. The thread will then `free` an unallocated memory area and my program crashes.

Here are the mentioned functions. `mmd` is a structure in global memory that is initialized from another function.

```
extern __device__ void wait(int* s) {
  while(atomicCAS(s, 0, 1) != 0);
}

extern __device__ void signal(int* s) {
  atomicExch(s, 0);
}

__device__ void pfree(Expression* node) {
  LinkedList* l = (LinkedList*) malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));
  l->cell = node;
  node->type = EMPTY;
  node->funcidx = 0;
  node->name = NULL;
  node->len = 0;
  node->value = 0;
  node->numParams = 0;
  free(node->params);

  int targetBin = (blockIdx.x * mmd.bucketSize + threadIdx.x) / BINSIZE;
  /*
   * The for loop and subsequent if are necessary to make sure that only one
   * thread in a warp is actively waiting for the lock on the semaphore.
   * Leaving this out will result in massive headaches.
   * See "CUDA by example", p. 273
   */

  for(int i = 0; i < WARPSIZE; i++) {
    if(((threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) % WARPSIZE) == i) {
      wait(&mmd.bucketSemaphores[targetBin]);
        l->next = mmd.freeCells[targetBin];
        mmd.freeCells[targetBin] = l;
      signal(&mmd.bucketSemaphores[targetBin]);
    }
  }
}

__device__ Expression* pmalloc() {
  Expression* retval = NULL;
  int i = 0;

  int bucket = (blockIdx.x * mmd.bucketSize + threadIdx.x) / BINSIZE;

  while(retval == NULL && i < mmd.numCellBins) {
    retval = pmallocBucket((i + bucket) % mmd.numCellBins);
    i++;
  }

  if(retval == NULL) {
    printf("(%u, %u) Out of memory\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
  }

  return retval;
}

__device__ Expression* pmallocBucket(int bucket) {
  Expression* retval = NULL;

  if(bucket < mmd.numCellBins) {
    LinkedList* l = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < WARPSIZE; i++) {
      if(((threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x) % WARPSIZE) == i) {
        wait(&mmd.bucketSemaphores[bucket]);
          l = mmd.freeCells[bucket];

          if(l != NULL) {
            retval = l->cell;
            mmd.freeCells[bucket] = l->next;
          }
        signal(&mmd.bucketSemaphores[bucket]);
        free(l);
      }
    }
  }

  return retval;
}
```

I am quite at a loss. I do not know what is actually going wrong and all my attempts so far to clear it up have been unsuccesful. Any help is greatly appreciated.

P. S.: Yes, I do realize that the use of atomic operations and semaphores is less than ideal for CUDA applications. But in this case, as of yet I have no idea how this could be implemented differently and my project is on an absolutely fixed deadline that is approaching really fast, so this will have to do.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the list manipulation is fully performed inside the critical section protected by the semaphore, without using stale data from before the semaphore was acquired.

Declare `l->next` and `mmd.freeCells` as volatile, or manipulate them through atomic functions (`atomicExch()`).

Alternatively you could use inline assembly with suitable cache operators. Using `mov.cg` for the load should be enough to ensure no locally cached value is used, together with a `__threadfence()` right before the `signal()` to make sure the write has reached global memory before the semaphore is released. Make sure to use `asm volatile(...)`, or again the compiler would be free to move the entire inline asm out of the critical section.

Comment: I have now declared both `l->next` and `mmd.freeCells` as volatile and added `__threadfence()` in front of `signal()` in `pfree()` and `pmallocBucket()`. Unfortunately the error persists.

I will now try to use `atomicExch()`...

Comment: Using `atomicExch()` does not make a difference either.

I have just collected an example where three other threads successfully removed elements from the same list, before a thread failed. The failing thread is run in a different warp than the non-failing thread.